# Learn android by tutorial that uses eclipse, but i use android studio.

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Hello I am learning android development. I have android studio downloaded. I have found one good tutorial, and it uses eclipse. The tutorial seems very good, but I think I will have problems due to differences in IDE. And also there is something called gradle. And I don't want to use Eclipse since android studio is official IDE for android. Is there a big differences between studio and eclipse such that i will have serious issues learning android by this tutorial.

Comment: It shouldn't, just some minor differences in the Manifest and Gradle. The rest should be the same.

Comment: I think it's wise to use Android Studio, and the base code you write in Eclipse and Android Studio should't be obvious different, in fact, they should be almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is in the part related to compiling, debugging, and running your code. For me, the transition from Eclipse to AS took me two days. Now I'm more used to AS than Eclipse.

As long as your tutorial teach you how to write code, not debug, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out TheNewBoston, they got a part there for Android Studio
https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=278